# Cant build project with Android Studio 2.3 and Gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, android-studio-2.3

I've cloned project https://github.com/mpcjanssen/simpletask-android.git but when I try to open it on Android Studio 2.3 (recently updated) it just wont buid the project.

I'll try to eaplain in steps:

**1)** Deleted everything in folder "..../simpletask-android" from my hard drive.
**2)** Started Android Studio and selected New Project from Github
**3)** After downloading the source code from Github Android Studio showed me the following screen and I adopted a Next-Next-Finish behavior, without changing anything.
[image]
**4)** Next, AS started building the project according to settings.gradle found in the project's root folder. There is a small dialog on the picture showing this.
**5)** Suddenly AS requested me to choose a gradle project data to import (?!) as shown in the image
[image]
**6)** Next message I got was this in the image below.  Project 'simpletask-android' is not a Gradle-based project
[image]
**7)** Next point is gradle breaking and telling me
  "Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'."  and

"22:22 Gradle sync failed: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)"

[image]

I tried to update Kotlin's version as it says in the Event Log but nothing happened...

I also tried to check the Log as it says and this is what I had:

2017-03-21 22:22:54,418 [1045087]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
...

Caused by: org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
...

Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
... 64 more

2017-03-21 22:22:54,423 [1045092]   WARN - ect.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask -
2017-03-21 22:22:54,423 [1045092]   INFO - ect.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask - A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

How can I fix this?

UPDATE: I uninstalled AS 2.3 and installed 2.2
Everything worked just fine. Then I thought it was solved and updated AS again into 2.3... So silly... I'm back to the start of this problem, guys...

Comment: Try building using Gradle on the command line?

Comment: I've cloned the repo and built project without problems (Android Studio 2.3 and Kotlin Plugin 1.1.1 installed)

Comment: OK. I'll try to edit the post describing each step I took.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong...

The project's build.gradle file had a mistake...

The original says:

```
buildscript {
    //other stuff
    dependencies {
        //something else
        classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-android-gradle-plugin:${dokka_version}"
    }
}
```

But it should be:

```
buildscript {
    //other stuff
    dependencies {
        //something else
        classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-gradle-plugin:${dokka_version}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

do it:

1. download latest version of gradle from https://gradle.org/releases
2. extract that to '`C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle`'
3. open android studio and go to '`File>Setting>Build, Execution,Deployment>Gradle`' and choose latest gradle folder from `Gradle Home` directory
4. Restart Android Studio and enjoy it.

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

open *prjectdir/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties*

and set

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

open the project gradle (not gradle inside the module) and set

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0+'
}
```

And also check the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html).

Hope it helps